# How to calculate the total number of ETH transmitted to the network every day?

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to calculate the amount of money sent from one address to another on the Ethereum network but I can't find any block explorer API that provides such information.

What is the best way to do that ?

Should I monitor stats from every blocks ? if so what information is usefull as there is nothing like volume transmitted in the basic stats from Etherchain of Etherscan.

https://etherchain.org/documentation/api/#api-Statistics-GetBasic_stats

Thanks!

Comment: This may be of interest. https://etherscan.io/txs?dt=1511568000
Showing all transactions that took place on a given day - with tx value associated

Comment: Thanks but I would like to use the API.